Magento 2 all admin ajax requests are returning html instead of json
I have migrated the Magento 2 code to a different server and setup the same codebase on my local/wamp server.
The admin pages are not showing any data but on my local/wamp server all admin pages like Sales Order are displaying orders.
After debugging the sales order page I have found that admin order ajax request on wamp server is returning json but on the different server it is returning html.
The live server has amazon CloudFront and threatx integrated.
On Local/Wamp server below request is returning json data for orders(example request):
http://abc.local/admin_4ajzfg/mui/index/render/key/d1ee5ae1cb3aa5c668504a2d52544fb6abbb33d4f5dd16c1c9ea2610d6b7d3b9/?namespace=sales_order_grid&search=sand&keywordUpdated=false&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D=true&paging%5BpageSize%5D=20&paging%5Bcurrent%5D=1&sorting%5Bfield%5D=created_at&sorting%5Bdirection%5D=desc&isAjax=true
On a different server the below request is returning html data(example request):
https://abc.test/admin_4ajzfg/mui/index/render/key/24b04907fe1ae7ed4540d48e6515fb3e39978687ebc0c93b3874ddd2bbbda7c7/?namespace=sales_order_grid&search=sandeep&keywordUpdated=false&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D=true&paging%5BpageSize%5D=20&paging%5Bcurrent%5D=1&sorting%5Bfield%5D=created_at&sorting%5Bdirection%5D=desc&isAjax=true

<!--
/**
 * Copyright &copy; Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<div class="admin__data-grid-outer-wrap" data-bind="scope: 'sales_order_grid.sales_order_grid'">
    <div data-role="spinner" data-component="sales_order_grid.sales_order_grid.sales_order_columns" class="admin__data-grid-loading-mask">
        <div class="spinner">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() -->
    <!-- /ko -->
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {"*": {"Magento_Ui/js/core/app": more_code_is_here}}
    </script>
</div>



I tried to check the difference, but both URLs return error messages

The problem was amazon cloudfront was not passing the accept header to the application. After configuring the clodufront behaviour the application started returing the json response.
